# Slowing down Rubocop warnings in Atom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-editor

Is there a way to get a bigger delay between typing and getting a warning from Rubocop in Atom?

I find the warnings distracting and would like to increase the delay before they show up. Or even disable dynamic warnings altogether. Are either possible?

Comment: You can adjust the delay from Atom's preferences package manager.  Go to the settings of the "linter" package where you can adjust the "Lint As You Type Interval".  300ms is the default.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been looking in all the wrong places.

Comment: That worked and it was very helpful. If you'll post it as an answer I'd be happy to up vote and select it.

Answer (score 2):

The "Lint As You Type Interval" for all installed linters has a global setting in the linter package settings.

1. Open Settings with `cmd-,`
2. Click on Packages in the left side menu.
3. Type `linter` into the "Filter by package name" field.
4. Click anywhere in the linter package box that shows up below.
5. Find the "Lint As You Type Interval" setting near the top.
6. Enter the number of milliseconds you want the delay. Default is 300.
7. Or turn it off completely by unchecking the "Lint As You Type" check-box.

Hope this helps!